# C++ - Inaccurate conversion from float to int following a division

Tags: c++

## Problem encoutered

In my program (C++ with Qt), I need to store a float value (let's call it `step`) which is divisible by 0.15. It is required to store this value as an integer which is the result of the division of `step` by `0.15`. This did the trick:

```
int storedValue;
[...]
storedValue = step / 0.15;
```

Unfortunately, for reasons I ignore, some `step` values (such as 300.15 or 300.30) aren't divided correctly: when `step` has the value `300.15`, `storedValue` is `2000` instead of being `2001`. Similarly, `300.30` as a step gives `storedValue` a value of `2001`. Then, `300.45` would correctly give `storedValue` 2003, and so on.

I have no idea why `300.15` and `300.30` have this bug, nor if there are any other values that trigger this bug.

## Solutions tried

I think the C++ conversion from `float` to `int` is the issue, since I checked the result of the division as a float and it is correct, so I made a float value to hold the result of the division, and use `storedValue = static_cast<int>(floatResult)`, hoping it would make for a better conversion. And, weirdly enough, `300.15` has now the correct `storedValue` of `2001`, but the bug still happen with `300.30`, giving the same `storedValue` of `2001`.

The current solution I have tried, but am unhappy with since it does not understand the problem and is not robust, is the following:

```
float floatResult = step / 0.15;
int storedValue = static_cast<int>(floatResult);
float verification = static_cast<float>(storedValue);

// If storedValue is false, verification will be different of floatResult
if (floatResult != verification) {
    storedValue = storedValue + 1;
    verification = static_cast<float>(storedValue);
    // Case I have never experienced, but since I can't understand the problem, I need to be careful
    if (floatResult != verification) {
        storedValue = storedValued - 2;
        verification = static_cast<float>(storedValue);
        if (floatResult != verification) {
            // Throw error
        }
    }
}
```

I found nothing relevant on the matter, since I am sure the result of this division is an integer (the user can't input a `step` not divisible by 0.15), so I don't see how precision matters here. Do someone have an idea about why this problem happens ? And/or how to improve my solution ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: You may try to use `= std::lround (step/0.15)`

Comment: On that note, you can see this by checking the values in a debugger or printing. e.g. 300.149994, 0.150000006 and 2000.99988. Conversion from float to int then *rounds down*.

Comment: @Damien I should have said, I tried using `std::round`, but it looks like my C++ version is not recent enough.

Comment: `std::lround` is available since C++11. Which compiler are use using? Did you use the C++11 flag? Did you include `<cmath>`?

Comment: If really `std::lround` is not available, and if `step` is positive, then you can try `static_cast<int>(step/0.15 + 0.5)` for example

Comment: @Damien `step` can be negative. I can use `std::floor` being careful about those negatives values.

Comment: It occured to me, since it is a Qt project, I can use the `qRound()` method instead of `std::round`. I use it to round the result of the division. Case solved.